# iOS: Play htaccess protected mp4 video directly in browser

Tags: ios, .htaccess, video, mp4

I have a protected directory on my server. In this directory I have uploaded a video. Now if I request this video on Android in a browser it works like a charm. If I request this video on the latest version of iOS it doesn't play.

I already tried to access the video with

```
http://username:password@myServer.com/myDirectory/myFile.mp4
```

But that brings up a "phishing attack" in iOS Browser.

I don't want to embed the video with HTML, I want to play it directly. How can I realize this with iOS and htaccess protection?

Many thanks!

// EDIT:
I want to make sure, that this problem is just because of the htaccess protection. iOS seems to have a problem with playing a video that is protected.

Comment: did you fund any solution? i am also facing the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately no. My workaround was that I moved all videos out of the public directory. After that I created a simple PHP login that will after you've successfully logged in copy the requested video into a temporary folder with the encrypted IP as a filename. You can then redirect to the video in the temporary folder which is without a htaccess protection. A cronjob will delete all movies after 15 minutes